# How to loop through an object to find a specific property based on user search input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is a project for my Javascript class.

I am building a website where people can search and book hotel rooms based on hotel name & selected arrival / departure times.

I have already figured out how to loop through my hotel objects names & display search results if the user inputs a valid hotel name.

I have set booked dates for each hotel & have set up dates which the user may input.

However, I can't figure out how to loop through my hotels & search for the booked dates I have preset.

My goal is to remove the hotels that are booked from the users search result page, showing only hotels that are available.

JS:

```
var userDates = ['1/1/2016', '2/2/2016', '3/3/2016', '4/4/2016']; // User Selected Dates

var rooms = [
  {
    hotel: "Bellagio", // Name
    guests: '2 Guests',
    price: '$350 / Night',
    size: '400 Square Feet',
    booked: ['1/1/2016', '1/2/2016', '1/3/2016', '1/4/2016'] // Booked Dates
  },
  {
    hotel: "The Venetian", // Name
    guests: '2 Guests',
    price: '$350 / Night',
    size: '400 Square Feet',
    booked: ['9/1/2016', '9/2/2016', '9/3/2016', '9/4/2016'] // Booked Dates
  },
  {
    hotel: "Wynn Resort", // Name
    guests: '2 Guests',
    price: '$350 / Night',
    size: '400 Square Feet',
    booked: ['9/1/2016', '9/2/2016', '9/3/2016', '9/4/2016'] // Booked Dates
  }
];

var available = [];

rooms.forEach(function(room) { 
  console.log("Check for availability of " + room.hotel); 
  var reserved = false;

  userDates.forEach(function(date) { 
    room.booked.forEach(function(booked) { 
      if (booked == date) { 
        console.log("All Booked. (Hide)"); 
        reserved = true; 
      }
    });
  });

  if (!reserved) { 
    available.push(room); 
    console.log(room.hotel + ' Has Rooms Available (Show)');
  }
});

// Listen for clicks on the button.
var searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
searchButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Get the text from the input.
  var term = document.getElementById('term').value;

  // Search the rooms for the text.
  var matched = []; // Empty Array
  for (var i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++) { 
    if (rooms[i].hotel.indexOf(term) !== -1) { 
      matched.push(rooms[i]); 
    }
  }

  // Show the rooms that match the text.
  for (var i = 0; i < matched.length; i++) {
    var theRoom = makeRoom(matched[i]); 
    var resultsArea = document.getElementById('results-area'); 
    resultsArea.appendChild(theRoom); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Your `userDate.forEach` loop is declaring all rooms booked if one of the userDates is in `room.booked`

Comment: thank you for your response, I was wondering if you can go a little bit more in detail?